# Django Rest-framework, JWT authentication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-rest-framework-jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm newbie in Django Restframework. I use JWT to make login, register API, everythings worked well, I want to GET a user information with authenticated (tokens). This is my code for UserViewSet

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer 
    authentication_classes = [IsAuthenticated,]
```

I've tested on Postman but i received: "'IsAuthenticated' object has no attributes 'authenticate'"

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'NONE_FIELD_ERRORS_KEY':'error',
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

Could you please to help me to solve this promblem? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

[`IsAuthenticated`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#isauthenticated) is not an [authentication class](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/). It's a [permission class](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/).

You would put it in `permission_classes` to allow any authenticated user access to that view set, while authentication (the mechanism of figuring out who the user for that request is) would be handled by that default JWT authentication:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer 
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated,]
```

Comment: Thank you, I saw my mistake